# Displaying data of particular user on to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, odbc

I want to show particular customer detail on to java  page using `JTable`
when I enter customer ID then pressed on then I want all details of the customer on to same window or another window?

How to do it?  I tried using following code but fail.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public abstract class Bill extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JTextField textFieldId; 
JLabel l1;
JLabel l2;  
    JButton b2;
Container c = getContentPane();
    ResultSet rs1 = null;        
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();

Bill()
{
    super("Shree Datta Digambar");
    setBounds(140,250,777,555);
    c.setLayout(null);
    textFieldId = new JTextField();
    l1 = new JLabel("New Customer Entry :-");
    l2 = new JLabel("Customer Id");
    l1.setBounds(10,10,340,20);
    l2.setBounds(10,20,140,70);     
    textFieldId.setBounds(10,70,70,20);             
    b2 = new JButton("Ok");     
    b2.setBounds(10,160,50,20);         
    c.add(b2);
    c.add(l1);
    c.add(l2);
    c.add(textFieldId);                
            setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                
            b2.addActionListener(this);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Bill bc=new Bill() {};
    }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            System.out.println("You clicked the button");                
            if(e.getSource()==b2)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Connection con;
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Bill.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
          con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:devendra");                      
                    java.sql.Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(null);
                    ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT FROM Customer 
                                          where Customer_Id = ?");
                    rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
                    while(rs1.next())
                    {
                        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
             rs1.getString(1),rs1.getString(2),rs1.getInt(3),rs1.getString(4) });
                    }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You successfully Enter the Entry");
                }
            catch (SQLException s) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter the Detail Correctly");
                    }        
            }
        }}
```

Comment: `" i tried using following code but fail so any body can help me out from these error then please help me ..."` -- what errors? Which line?

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form. 3) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: 4) Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space.

Comment: why don't you use WindowBuilder to design your UI more easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things that I can see that won't help you.

1. `Bill` is `abstract`.  There is no reason for it to be `abstract`.
2. There is no `JTable`.  Which is actually very surprising, as you have an actual `TableModel`
3. You're using a `null` layout.  This will never help you.
4. You're extending from a `JFrame`.  This not a great idea as it immediately prevents you from re-using this class in other forms.
5. Your query does not bind any values to the variable parameter.
6. Your exception handling leaves a little to be desired...

A better approach might look something like...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable();
    }

    public TestTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Bill());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Bill extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        JTextField textFieldId;
        JLabel l1;
        JLabel l2;
        JButton b2;
        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();

        public Bill() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel fields = new JPanel();

            textFieldId = new JTextField(10);
            l1 = new JLabel("New Customer Entry :-");
            l2 = new JLabel("Customer Id");
            b2 = new JButton("Ok");

            fields.add(l2);
            fields.add(textFieldId);
            fields.add(b2);

            add(fields, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            b2.addActionListener(this);

            // Don't forget to add a table.
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(dtm)));

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
            if (e.getSource() == b2) {
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                try {
                    Connection con;
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:devendra");
                    ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT FROM Customer where Customer_Id = ?");
                    // You must bind the parameter with a value...
                    ps.setString(1, textFieldId.getText());
                    rs1 = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs1.next()) {
                        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{
                            rs1.getString(1), rs1.getString(2), rs1.getInt(3), rs1.getString(4)});
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You successfully Enter the Entry");
                } catch (SQLException s) {
                    System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
                    s.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter the Detail Correctly");
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Failed to perform query: " + exp.getMessage());
                } finally {

                    try {
                        ps.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think you might want to spend a little more time reading through...

- [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Comment: i will follow u r instruction> Thanks alot again.
God Bless u...:) :)

Comment: it give me enter the detail correctly error why these is so..
i want detail of that particular customer on the screen in tabular format ???
sorry these is first major project i am doing so help me out
......

Comment: That's not the exception, that's the message.  In the `try-catch` block where the message is displayed, you need to printing/logging the exception.  Which based on you example might look like `s.printStackTrace()`

Comment: as u told me "// You must bind the parameter with a value..." these comment i made these changes in code instead of these "ps.setString(1, textFieldId.getText());" i change to "ps.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(textFieldId.getText()));"
is these possible ?

Comment: when i enter the proper customer id then i got these error as" enter the detail corectly ?

Comment: And, the message is being displayed in response to an exception being thrown by your code, which triggers the message, but (if you used my example), will also dump the exception to the console.  It's this information that we need to diagnose what is going wrong.  I don't have access to your database, so I can't run your code.

Comment: my database is like
Customer_Id     Customer_Name   Contact   News_Paper_Name
1                   abc         123           xyz
2                   pqr         786           lmn
so when i put customer id is 1 then i want all its detail must be apper in table
how to do ??

Comment: If, for some reason, there is an error, if you have followed my example, in the `catch` section of the `try-catch`, it will dump the exception to the console.  This will help you diagnose what the error is.  The basic example outlines the requirements you need to achieve, but if, for example, the database call fails, I can't help without the details of the exception

Comment: The exception! What is printed out to the console?

Comment: And netbeans has an output window where it displays the output of the program

Comment: yes.i mean to say when i run the code i got perticular error that i told u already.and my database is like colume 1 ,2,3,4 has name like customer id ,customer name,contacts,newspaper name,

Comment: Okay, if, you are actually dumping the stack trace, it will be in the output window.  I can't help you without it...

Comment: hey man i got the proper solution.
just simple mistake in the code i corrected it..